# Save the variables of an object to then be able to initialise another object with those variables

Tags: c++

What I am trying to achieve is this:

Let's say I have a class `Score`. This class has an `int` variable and a `char*` variable.

Now when I have an object `Score score`, I would like to be able to save the value of those variables (I guess to a file). So now this file has an `int` variable and  a `char*` variable that I can then access later to create a new `Score` object.

So I create `Score score(10, "Bert");`. I either do something like `score.SaveScore();` or the score gets saved when the game is over or the program exits, it doesn't matter.

Basically I am looking for the equivalent/correct way of doing this:

```
score.SaveScore(FILE file)
{
    file.var1 = score.score;
    file.var2 = score.name;
}
```

I realize this is probably very stupid and not done this way whatsoever! This is just me trying to explain what I am trying to achieve in the simplest way possible.

Anyway, when I run the program again, that original `Score score(10, "Bert")` does not exist any more. But I would like to be able to access the saved score(from file or wherever it may be) and create another Score object.

So it may look something like:

```
LoadScore(FILE file)
{
    Score newScore(file.var1, file.var2);
}
```

Again, just trying to show what I am trying to achieve.

The reason why I want to be able to access the variables again is to eventually have a Scoreboard, the Scoreboard would load a bunch of scores from the file.

Then when a new score is created, it is added to the scoreboard, compared to the other scores currently in the scoreboard and inserted in the right position     (like a score of 6 would go in between 9 and 4).

I feel like this was a bit long winded but I was trying to really explain myself well! Which I hope I did!

Anyway, I am not looking for someone to tell me how to do all of that.

All I am after is how to do the initial save to a file.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Look for the following term in your favorite search engine: *serialization*. Also consider using std::string, std::ofstream etc since you tagged this C++.

Comment: If your class has string data I suggest you use a `std::string` instead of a `char*`.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question - you might clear it up a bit -, however, we need to know to what extent do you want serialization. Do you want new object(s) to be constructed? Is it just POD, a purely hierarchical object set, or DAG or are there even circles? Have threads, if yes, can you 'pause' everything while you're serializing / deserializing? What about resources (e.g. `std::mutex<>, FILE`)? Many questions arise, so you might want to clarify scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `<fstream>` library, like this;

```
//example values
int x=10; 
float y=10.5;
const char* chars = "some random value";
string str(chars); //make string buffer for sizing
str.resize(20); //make sure its fixed size

//open a test.txt file, in the same dir for output
std::ofstream os("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary); //make it output binary 

//(char*) cast &x, sizeof(type) for values/write to file chars for x and y
os.write((char*)&x, sizeof(int)); //only sizeof(int) starting at &x
os.write((char*)&y, sizeof(float)); //cast as a char pointer
os.write(str.data(), sizeof(char)*str.size()); //write str data
os.close();

//the file test.txt will now have binary data in it

//to read it back in, just ifstream, and put that info in new containers, like this;
int in_x = 0; //new containters set to 0 for debug
float in_y = 0;
char inchar[20]; //buffer to write 20 chars to

ifstream is("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary); //read in binary

is.read((char*)&in_x, sizeof(int)); //write to new containers
is.read((char*)&in_y, sizeof(float));
is.read((char*)&inchar, sizeof(char)*20); //write char assuming 20 size
is.close();


//outputting will show the values are correctly read into the new containers
cout << in_x << endl;
cout << in_y << endl;
cout << inchar << endl;
```

Comment: This is great for fixed sized types but does nothing to show the OP how to write string data to a file.

Comment: ah, my bad, let me see if I can fix it

Comment: Now you have UB as `chars` is not 20 characters long.

Comment: what do you mean? it could be any size, its just so you know how much to write, make it 100 if you want

Comment: Yes but you are accessing memory you do not own. `os.write(chars, sizeof(char)*20)` is going to walk of the end of the array, which is UB.

Comment: Of course you are right, this should fix it. chars are messy by nature heh

Answer (score 0):

> I realize this is probably very stupid and not done this way whatsoever!

The entire software industry was stupid enough to have it done so many times that even a special term was invented for this operation - [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and nearly all C++ frameworks and libraries have implemented this in a various ways.
Since question is tagged with `C++` I would suggest you to look at [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) but there are many other implementations.

Do you need that file to be readable by a human? If yes than consider, for example, `XML` or `JSON` formats.

You don't need it be readable but want it be as compact as possible? Consider [google protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf)

Just start doing it and come with a more specific question(s).

As it was mentioned before, keep strings as `std:string` objects rather then `char*`

About writing/reading to/from files in C++ read about [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/)